# How can I ensure an enum declared inside a class is a managed enum?

Tags: visual-c++, enums

In Visual C++ (VS 2015) I can define a managed enum as follows:

```
public enum class Pet {
    Cat,
    Dog,
    Hamster,
};
```

and the keyword "public" is vitally important. Without it, it will not treat Pet as a managed enum, and you will not be able to access the text associated with the members of the enum using Enum::GetName, for example.

However, if I try and declare an enum inside a class, like so:

```
class Construction {

public :

    public enum class Fixing {
        Nut,
        Bolt,
        Rivet,
    };

};
```

I get this error message :

```
error C3379: 'Construction::Fixing': a nested class cannot have an assembly access specifier as part of its declaration
```

If I remove the "public" from the declaration, like this:

```
class Construction {

public :

    enum class Fixing {
        Nut,
        Bolt,
        Rivet,
    };

};
```

and then add the following code:

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{
    array<String^> ^names = Enum::GetNames( Construction::Fixing::typeid );
    for ( int i = 0; i < names->Length; ++i ) {
        Console::WriteLine( names[ i ] );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

then it will compile without complaint, but the output is not what I might expect. There is no output at all. Delving deeper I find that Enum::GetNames is returning a zero length array. It seems the compiler is treating Fixing as an unmanaged enum, and is using the C++ 11 syntax for "enum class".

So, how do I change the code so that Fixing is a managed enum?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I need to make sure the class in which the enum is declared is a managed class, like so:

```
ref class Construction {

public :

    enum class Fixing {
        Nut,
        Bolt,
        Rivet,
    };

};
```

Then the code that writes out the names of the members works. However, I still think the line "enum class Fixing" looks rather ambiguous. It isn't immediately clear that this is a managed enum.